# Putting double value into TextView

Tags: android, parsing, textview, double, numberformatexception

In my Android app I am calculating a double value using values entered into EditTexts and trying to put the answer into a TextView. My code is this:

```
double scoreDouble;
TextView score;
EditText gpa;
EditText sat;
EditText act;
Button calc;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gpa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gpa);
    String gpaString = gpa.getText().toString();
    if(gpaString.equals("")){
        gpaString = "0";
    }
    final double gpaDouble = Double.parseDouble(gpaString);     
    sat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sat);
    String satString = sat.getText().toString();
    if(satString.equals("")){
        satString = "0";
    }
    final int satInt = Integer.parseInt(satString);     
    act = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.act);
    String actString = act.getText().toString();
    if(actString.equals("")){
        actString = "0";
    }
    final int actInt = Integer.parseInt(actString);     
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);            
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(actInt/36>satInt/2400){
                scoreDouble= (0.6*gpaDouble*25)+(0.4*(actInt/36)*100);
                String scoreString = Double.toString(scoreDouble);
                score.setText("Your score is "+scoreString);
            }else{
                scoreDouble = (0.6*gpaDouble*25)+(0.4*(satInt/2400)*100);
                String scoreString = Double.toString(scoreDouble);
                score.setText("Your score is "+scoreString);
            }


        }
    });
}
```

As of now, when the button is pressed the TextView says: "Your score is 0.0." I feel this has something to do with the fact that I set the default values of the EditTexts to 0. Before I did this, I was getting an error stating NumberFormatException: invalid double: "". If this is the problem, how should I fix it. If that is not the problem, what it?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? The fact that it displays 0.0 instead of 0?

Comment: Try to use String.valueOf(<double value>)  instead of Double.toString(<value>)

Comment: The problem is that it should not be displaying 0.0. It does this no matter what I enter into the edittexts. Also changing it to String.valueOf did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the actInt and satInt as final variables, and they will be assigned to a value only once (when the execution of the onCreate method)  and the initial value will be zero as at the begining the edittext contain nothing.

To solve this issue:

move he actInt and satInt from local variables to a field variables and remove the final keyword.  (I mean define those variables as a private variables inside the class)  and assign the values for the variables inside the onclick Method.

```
public class test extends Activity {

double scoreDouble;
TextView score;
EditText gpa;
EditText sat;
EditText act;
Button calc;

private int satInt;
private int actInt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gpa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gpa);

    sat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sat);

    act = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.act);

    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gpaString = gpa.getText().toString();
            if (gpaString.equals("")) {
                gpaString = "0";
            }
            double gpaDouble = Double.parseDouble(gpaString);

            String satString = sat.getText().toString();
            if (satString.equals("")) {
                satString = "0";
            }
            int satInt = Integer.parseInt(satString);

            String actString = act.getText().toString();
            if (actString.equals("")) {
                actString = "0";
            }
            int actInt = Integer.parseInt(actString);
            if (actInt / 36 > satInt / 2400) {
                scoreDouble = (0.6 * gpaDouble * 25)
                        + (0.4 * (actInt / 36) * 100);
                String scoreString = Double.toString(scoreDouble);
                score.setText("Your score is " + scoreString);
            } else {
                scoreDouble = (0.6 * gpaDouble * 25)
                        + (0.4 * (satInt / 2400) * 100);
                String scoreString = Double.toString(scoreDouble);
                score.setText("Your score is " + scoreString);
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked out. Thank you very much. Respect.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything on your `onCreate` method. So all your code is called at the start of your application. At this moment, your `EditText`s are empty and your code goes to these parts:

```
 if(gpaString.equals("")){
        gpaString = "0";
 }

 if(actString.equals("")){
        actString = "0";
 }

 if (actString.equals("")) {
        actString = "0";
 }
```

Which means that your values `gpaDouble`, `actInt` and `satInt` are equals 0.

Then, you are doing the following:

```
scoreDouble = (0.6*gpaDouble*25)+(0.4*(satInt/36)*100);
```

and this:

```
scoreDouble = (0.6*gpaDouble*25)+(0.4*(satInt/2400)*100);
```

With the 0 values, your `scoreDouble` value can only be equal to 0.

To fix it, get your `EditText`s' texts in the `onClick` method of your `Button`.